# How to access a ReactJS function components property via a ref?

Tags: reactjs

I have a MediaRecorder component on my page that contains a MediaStream once the user starts recording audio or video. I need to access that stream and pass the stream to a socketio connection. I need a reference to the MediaRecorder component (node) from my socketio code. New to react so not sure if or how I can access it. I am struggling to use ref and to gain access to the stream.

Code for the audio and video nodes.

```
{state === 1 && <RecordAudio />}
{state === 2 && <RecordVideo />}
```

Code for function that renders the MediaRecorder. How do I access `audioRecorderRef` from the socketio/audioStreamer code below?

```
function RecordAudio(props) {
  const audioRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  isVideo = false;

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log('starting audioPreview ========');
  //   if (stream) audioRef.current.srcObject = stream;
  // }, [stream]);

  return (
    <ReactMediaRecorder
      audio
      render={({ status, startRecording, stopRecording, previewStream, mediaBlobUrl }) => (
        <Row>
          {status === 'recording' ? (
            <AudioPreview stream={previewStream} ref={previewStream} />
          ) : (
            <audio src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay />
          )}
          <Controls
            status={status}
            startRecording={startRecording}
            stopRecording={stopRecording}
            mediaBlobUrl={mediaBlobUrl}
          />
        </Row>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Socket code that will need the reference to the stream; `this.theStream` needs to be the ref I am after.

```
const socket = useSocket('streaming-connected', (connectionMessage) => {
    console.log(`Connection Message: ${JSON.stringify(connectionMessage)}`);
    if (connectionMessage.type === 'connected') {
      setJobId(connectionMessage.id);
      audioStreamer.startStreaming();
      console.log(JSON.stringify(canvasRef));
      audioVisual({ canvasRef, analyser, bufferLength: bufferLength });
    }
  });

  const constraints = { audio: true, video: false };
  const audioStreamer = useUserMedia({
    constraints,
    streamListener: (stream) => {
      console.log('Streamlistener in streamcontroller line 64 abut to connect');
      let source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.theStream);
      source.connect(analyser);
    },
    dataCb: (data) => socket.emit('stream', data),
  });
```

Or can I circumvent this by grabbing `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`in the audioStreamer code?

Comment: Anything needed globally can be referenced by `Context API` or `Redux`. Have you considered trying that out? In this case, not the react `MediaRecorder` component but the stream object from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`.

Comment: This is a one page app so Redux is a massive overkill. I tried navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) but it doesn't work.

Comment: 'React Context API` is built-in for global objects management. If the stream object is a singleton, can this get stored in one place and used throughout the project ( in your case in component and socket)?